# How can I get the query that would be run for the archive page?

Tags: query, archives

When a user visits a post type archive page on my site, I've got a bunch of hooks and filters that run on that query and get it just so. How can I, in a different request, say "I want the query that would run when I go to /archives" so I can get those same posts in a different context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each of your hooks & filters handlers, in addition to checking for archive conditions, check for a custom query var that you can then set for a custom/manual query. For example, where you might have:

```
function wpse_223991_pre_get_posts( $wp_query ) {
    if ( $wp_query->is_main_query() && $wp_query->is_post_type_archive( 'my_post_type' ) ) {
        // Awesome custom stuff
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_223991_pre_get_posts' );
```

... change it to:

```
function wpse_223991_pre_get_posts( $wp_query ) {
    if ( ! $do_it = $wp_query->is_main_query() && $wp_query->is_post_type_archive( 'my_post_type' ) )
        $do_it = $wp_query->get( 'custom_stuff_please' );

    if ( $do_it ) {
        // Awesome custom stuff
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_223991_pre_get_posts' );
```

Now in addition to it running your main custom post type archive, you can trigger it whenever you set `custom_stuff_please` in a custom query:

```
$query = new WP_Query([ 'custom_stuff_please' => true ]);
```